# How to find points of drawcontour of a detected image?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, points

I want to find points of a contour which is draw on object after following operation like background subtraction , findcontour ,drawcontour.
My object is moving so that my contour is also not proper . and i want to find of maximum and minimum points on contour which is draw on object.
Can anyone tell me how to find?
My object is moving car and camera view is top.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. I'll say what I think I know and you correct me. You have a video taken from a moving car, or of a moving car, and you want to detect contours, I.e. lines through each still image that join pixels of equal colour. Is that anywhere near correct?

Comment: hey @adrin may . thanx for asking. no my object is moving which is car and my view of camera is top view. and i want points of contour which is independent of drwacontour. beacause after operation of drawcontour I find points according to rectangle which i can't detect that what are maximum or minimum. see my below comment for it

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<Point>> allContours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Mat _temp = image.clone();
findContours(_temp, allContours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

allContours is contour's vector.
you can access points of each contours.

============================================================================

all points of contous will be draw by below code.
[image: original]
[image: draw contour]
[image: draw points of contour]

```
    vector<vector<Point>> allContours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    Mat _temp = imageGray.clone();
    Mat ptDraw = Mat::zeros(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC3);
    findContours(_temp, allContours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for(int i=0;i<allContours.size();i++)
    {
        drawContours(image, allContours, i, Scalar(0,0,255), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );

        for(int j=0;j<allContours.at(i).size();j++)
        {
            Point pt = allContours.at(i).at(j);
            circle(ptDraw,pt,1,Scalar(0,0,255),CV_FILLED);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks kim for your reply.I have used this method,but what I get is 4 Adjacent points on left upper corner from contour.I want points from all 4 corners.Do you know,there is any method to achieve this?

Comment: @coco if you want corner of the object, i recommended try corner detect. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html
Or you can find bounding rectangle of the contour, and get 4 points of the rectangle.